# UPDATE command in a JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column in my table, but that column stores a JSON Object, but for that I need to do a where with a JSON as well.

This is how the data is stored in my RG column:

```
{
   "Id":"00000",
   "Number":"12345678",
   "Emitter":"SSP/SP",
   "Uf":"SP",
   "Emission":"2020-03-04T03:00:00Z"
}
```

First I would like to know what is wrong with this SELECT statement:

```
select * from People where JSON_VALUE (Rg, '$.Uf') LIKE '%35%'
```

And my UPDATE command I tried to do as follows:

```
update People set Rg = JSON_MODIFY (Rg, '$.Uf', 'SP') where JSON_VALUE (Rg, '$.Uf') LIKE '%35%'
```

Could someone help me make the select and this update, please? And what's wrong with my commands? I couldn't understand how to do these two commands when a `JSON OBJECT` is involved.

Comment: Please don't use images to show data, instead format it as text as that is much easier to read.

Comment: Is the space between `$` and `.uf` on purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I don't saw the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your SELECT query and UPDATE statements are fine. I tried below with test setup. I did not face any issue.

**Test Setup**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  a int,
  rg NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )

 INSERT INTO Test
 values (1, N'{
   "Id":"00000",
   "Number":"12345678",
   "Emitter":"SSP/SP",
   "Uf":"SP",
   "Emission":"2020-03-04T03:00:00Z"
}');
```

**Running Select Query**

```sql
select * from Test where JSON_VALUE (Rg, '$.Uf') LIKE '%SP%'
```

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a |                                                   rg                                                    |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | { "Id":"00000", "Number":"12345678", "Emitter":"SSP/SP", "Uf":"SP", 
"Emission":"2020-03-04T03:00:00Z" } |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Updating and Selecting to verify whether update was successful**

```sql
update Test 
set rg = JSON_MODIFY(rg, '$.Uf', 'MP') 
where JSON_VALUE(rg, '$.Uf') LIKE '%SP%'
```

```sql
select * from Test;
```

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a |                                                   rg                                                    |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | { "Id":"00000", "Number":"12345678", "Emitter":"SSP/SP", "Uf":"MP", 
"Emission":"2020-03-04T03:00:00Z" } |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```